# Use google fonts in Angular throws network error [_ngcontent-X];400[_ngcontent-X];600[_ngcontent-X]

Tags: angular, google-font-api

I am seeing a lot of network errors like this:

```
>     Request URL: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@200;300[_ngcontent-c6];400[_ngcontent-c6];600[_ngcontent-c6];700&display=swap
>     Request Method: GET
>     Status Code: 400
```

it is adding [ng-content] to the request url, is there a way to fix this?

here you can see the error in the network: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scss-demo-r7csxc?file=src/app/app.component.scss

Regards!

Comment: The workaround is to replace this:

Answer (score 0):

Workaround is to replace this:

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@200;300;400;600;700&display=swap');

With this:

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@200&display=swap');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@300&display=swap');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@400&display=swap');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@600&display=swap');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@700&display=swap');

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the compiler; escaping certain characters - semicolon in this case.

Escape them yourself using %3B

`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@200%3B300%3B400%3B600%3B700&display=swap');`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scss-demo-fg9bfg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss

Answer (score 0):

This occurred for me because someone had imported Google API's into a component style sheet instead of the root styles.

Specifically in my case there was an import of Google API's from the root to the component. The style sheets looked something like this:

***/component.scss**

```scss
@use "../styles/fonts";
```

**fonts.scss**

```scss
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600;700&display=swap");
```

The solution was to only have the reference in root style sheet and remove the one from the component styles.

I was able to identify the offending components by doing a text search on the generated files for "googleapis".